# is it possible to use two if/then/else below?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have this part of my query:

```
declare function local:accoppiamenti($snapshot){
for $ev in $snapshot/EV
let $stringa := $ev/accoppiamenti//accoppiamento/@specie
let $flag := true()
return(
    if($stringa[1]=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[2]!=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[3]=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[last()]=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[last()-1]!=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[last()-2]=$ev/specie/@cod)
    then(
        for $i in (4 to count($stringa)-3)
        return(
            if($stringa[$i]=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[$i+1]!=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[$i+2]=$ev/specie/@cod)
            then($flag=false())
            else()
        )
    )
    else($flag=false())
    if($flag=true())
    then(data("OK"))
    else()
)
};
```

The second block `if/then/else` in the extern cycle `for` don't work. How can I check the value of the variable flag? I need to see if I passed all the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sequence of booleans indicating a result for each test, and then test if any of the booleans is false.

```
declare function local:accoppiamenti($snapshot){
for $ev in $snapshot/EV
let $stringa := $ev/accoppiamenti//accoppiamento/@specie
let $flags := 
    if($stringa[1]=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[2]!=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[3]=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[last()]=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[last()-1]!=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[last()-2]=$ev/specie/@cod)
    then(
        for $i in (4 to count($stringa)-3)
        return(
            if($stringa[$i]=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[$i+1]!=$ev/specie/@cod and $stringa[$i+2]=$ev/specie/@cod)
            then(false())
            else(true())
        )
    )
    else(false())
return (if every $f in $flags satisfies $f then 'ok' else ()) 
};
```

This can be simplified but I have deliberately kept it close to the original.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a sequence, so you just need to add a comma after `else($flag=false())` to separate it from the next expression.

Comment: I'm not sure what the code is ultimately supposed to do, but it could be a misunderstanding of the expression: `$flag=false()`, which is a comparison (like `==` in some other languages) that returns an `xs:boolean`. It does not assign `$flag` to be `false()`.

Comment: I have found that putting a comma, the flag value back to true. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Variables in XQuery are immutable, so once assigned, values cannot be reassigned. The "correct" way to do it would be to rewrite your logic to not rely on a flag variable. However, I have seen people work around the immutability constraint by using multiple flags (`$flag1`, `$flag2`, etc.), but I don't recommend it.